# Proof that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x=e$.

Tags: calculus

I was at work and I was curious if there was a limit for the formula
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^2$$
And I became curious on Desmos to see if there would a different limit for
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x$$
It looked like it approached a constant value and, upon plugging it into a limit calculator, it returned
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x=e$$

What is the proof of this? I managed to work it down to $x^x(x-1)^{-x}$, but my calculus isn't good enough for me to work it past there...

Comment: What's the definition of $e$ that you are using?

Comment: @VarunVejalla, I'm using the definition of $e\approx2.718...$

Comment: That's just a decimal approximation, not an actual definition. A common definition of $e$ is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$. Do you want to start from there?

Comment: Maybe "definition" isn't the right word, considering that all the different "definitions" are all equivalent and define the same constant, but you need some starting point.

Comment: Oh... I don't study maths. I'm just interested in it. The definition I've been using recently is $e=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n!})+1$

Answer (score 4):

If you know that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac tx \right)^x = e^t$$ for any real $t$ you can use the particular choice $t = -1$ to find that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x-1}{x} \right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac 1x \right)^x = e^{-1} = \frac 1e.$$

Now take reciprocals and use an appropriate limit law.

Answer (score 4):

This is something you can remember when facing indetermination problems of the type $1^{\infty}$, it’s often used in many problems.

You have:

$$
\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x=e^{x \ln (\frac{x}{x-1})}
=e^{x \ln (1-\frac{1}{x-1})}$$
We know that when $X \rightarrow 0$, we have $\ln (1+X)$ equivalent to $X$. Therefore, when $x \rightarrow +\infty$, our expression is equivalent to $e^{\frac{x}{x-1}}$. You can now conclude that the limit of your expression is $e$, as you guessed it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log$ denote the natural logarithm.

For any $x>1$ we have, $$\dfrac{x}{x-1}>0$$ therefore,

$$\forall x>1,\left(\dfrac{x}{x-1} \right)^x= \mathrm{e}^{x\log\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}=\mathrm{e}^{-x \log\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}=e^{-x\log \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Moreover,
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \underset{+\infty}{\sim}-\frac{1}{x}$$

Therefore,
$$-x \log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) \underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$

Hence, using the fact $\exp$ is continuous,

$$\boxed{\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{x-1} \right)^x = e^1}$$